# Java Applet Not Working In Windows 7 but working in Windows XP

Tags: java, windows, applet

I have designed a java applet in Linux environment and then it is have tested in Windows XP. But it shows nothing when used in Windows 7. The java console shows that it is working as per requirement but still it only shows a white screen with the buttons visible but no output.

Can anybody help me in understanding the issue and how it can be solved?

Comment: Are you sure you are running the same version of Java and the same bit-ness in each case?  The version of Java and the version of your browser you use is more likely to matter than the choice of OS.

Comment: yes I updated the java version from the official site of java.

Comment: You updated with the same 32-bit vs 64-bit on all machines and that is the version which is being used?

Comment: Yes i did update the machine with the latest 32 bit java available. Still the applets opens and shows a white screen only.

Comment: Did you update *all* the machines to the same 32-bit version?  Not just the one which doesn't work to ensure it still works/doesn't as before?  Can you run the applet outside the browser, i.e. with the appviewer?

Comment: Well all that i did to solve the problem was to **Run the browser in _Run As Administrator_ mode**.
That solved the problem for Windows 7. But what is the difference between simple mode and the _Run as Administrator_ mode in Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

All I did was to provide the browser with administrative privileges by running it in **Run As Administrator** mode. Now my applet works fine and performs the assigned task.